# Flutter cache images when retrieved from external storage

Tags: flutter

in this code which i used in my application i want to cache images during i scroll grid view, basically when i scroll grid view that cause reload again images and cause of getting speeding low during scroll

is any way to cache images before put them into `GridView` like with `ImageCache`?

```
StreamBuilder<List<MediaModel>>(
  stream: _globalBloc.storageMediaBloc.imagesMedia$,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    final List<MediaModel> _allImages = snapshot.data;
    _allImages.map((image) => mediaFoldersList.add(MediaDropDownStructure(image.folder, image.folder)));
    final MediaModel _all = _allImages[1];
    return GridView.builder(
      controller: scrollController,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
      ), //change the numb
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio:1.0,
            child: Image(image: FileImage(File('${_all.files[index]}')),fit: BoxFit.cover,));
      },
      itemCount: _all.files.length,
    );
  }
),
```

Comment: just don't use the `builder` constructor, use the normal/unnamed constructor.

Comment: @hiwajalal what's your mean? i can't get your mean

Comment: this is for normal constructor => Creates a scrollable, 2D array of widgets with a custom SliverGridDelegate.

this for the builder constructor => Creates a scrollable, 2D array of widgets that are created on **demand**.

also take a look [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, try to move the file reading out of the grid builder:

```
  StreamBuilder<List<MediaModel>>(
  stream: _globalBloc.storageMediaBloc.imagesMedia$,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    final List<MediaModel> _allImages = snapshot.data;
    _allImages.map((image) => mediaFoldersList.add(MediaDropDownStructure(image.folder, image.folder)));
    final List<File> _all = _allImages[1].map((path) => File(path));

    return GridView.builder(
      controller: scrollController,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
      ), //change the numb
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio:1.0,
            child: Image(image: FileImage(_all[index]),fit: BoxFit.cover,));
      },
      itemCount: _all.files.length,
    );
  }
),
```

Comment: it doesn't any change :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue as yours where images are constantly re-rendering even if the images are stored locally.

```
return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio:1.0,
        child: Container(key: Key("1234"), child:Image(image: FileImage(File('${_all.files[index]}')),fit: BoxFit.cover,)))
```

I found that by adding a random key like `Key("1234")` would prevent the image from re-rendering.

Do try out the solution and let me know if it works.

Comment: i tested both of `${Random().nextInt(5)}` and `1234`, but it doesn't any change